# Create multiple index files for a single indirect DjVu file

Tags: djvu

Indirect DjVu file split documents into individual pages that can be linked to and loaded individually, yet be can still be navigated like a single document. They fill a gap between PDFs and web pages.

I want to create multiple index files for a single indirect DjVu document, in a very similar matter to this (from 2003).

http://www.djvu-soft.narod.ru/planetdjvu/multiple_index_files_for_a_single_indirect_djvu.htm

I want to use only ordinary free (libre) DjVu tools (djvulibre-plugin, pdf2djvu, etc.)

My use case is to convert a library of PDFs to a single indirect DjVu file, then create multiple indexes that show relevant pages suitable for different audiences.

I can get some of the way there by linking to specific pages from a web page, which works very well if djvulibre-plugin is installed. However the user then has to scroll (or jump) to specific pages in the same large set.

I could also build different indirect DjVu documents to match the needs to different audiences, but that would lead to lots of redundancy.

Can multiple indexes be created for a single indirect DjVu document using current free tools?